# Simple question for case $k=0$ in Artin Rees Lemma

Tags: commutative-algebra

In AM, Artin-Rees lemma, there is no constraint on integer $k$ but in most sources, Artin-Rees lemma is stated: "there exists an integer $k>0$ s.t. ..." My question is: is $k=0$ not a possibility?

Comment: @AlexWertheim The bracket is $(I^nM) \cap N = I^n(M \cap N)$. I can see the $\supseteq$ but how about the other way?

Comment: My bad, I misread the statement of Artin-Rees. I'll delete my comment, sorry.